# OpenCV - How to get the tangent of a polygonal curve

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get the tangent of a polygonal curve I got using approxPolyDP(), I have tried Hough lines and some mathematical formulas for gradient but none of them worked.
I want to get the tangent in the red marks in the image.

[image: Contour]

Comment: A tangent only just touches a circle, whereas the line joining the two red marks is more of a *"chord"*. Is that what you are looking for? What's the significance of the cyan line and other part of white line please?

Comment: the cyan is the result of the approxPolyDP() function sadly it wasn't able to detect the whole white line (because of the discontinuities) which is the canny result. I'm not looking for the line joining the 2 red marks but the tangent with the circular part in the red marks

Comment: So you currently only have the cyan, and want the tangent at each of the red marks?

Comment: yes exactly! and it' fine if I can get it at least in the bottom one